# Need confirmation regarding the solution of a simple probability question related to deck of cards?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

> Example 5: Two cards are drawn from a deck of cards.
>
> A: 1 s t card is a club
>
> B: 1 s t card is a 7
>
> C: 2 n d card is a heart.
>
> Find the following probabilities:
>
> (a) P(A or B)
>
> (b) P (B or A)
>
> (c) P (A and C)

I can easily solve (a) and (b).   But for (c) the solution in my book is as follows-

[image]

But I think it is not right. Because if the first card is a club the only 51 cards would be remaining.  So it should be $$13\div52*13\div51$$.

Please correct me if I am wrong or the book solution is wrong. I just need confirmation regarding this question.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: You are right. The book solution is wrong.